# How to make a Thread in Java wait for two different inputStreams to change?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

I am creating a program where there is a Server and many Clients. When a client connects to the server a thread is created to manage that client. Whenever a client sends a message the thread receives this message and sends it to the rest of threads. When a thread receives a message from another thread sends it to its client.

The problem I am having is that for this purpose one thread needs to wait for two different conditions at the same time:

1. A client sends a message
2. Another thread sends a message to that thread

The code I have right now is:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer);
synchronized (otherclientSockets) {
  for (Socket otherclientSocket : otherclientSockets) {
    if (!clientSocket.equals(otherclientSocket)) {
      otherclientSocket.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
  }
}
```

Right now when a thread receives the message from the client it resends the message to the rest of clients. How can I change this in order to work as described before?

Thank you :)

Comment: Using a Selector (answer below) is the right answer.  It's how basically all servers on the internet work.

Answer (score 2):

The normal pattern in Java is to make a thread per client. One thread can't wait for more than one InputStream at the same time.

If you want to wait for more than one thing on the same thread, you can "upgrade" to NIO. Then you can create a [`Selector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html), [register](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectableChannel.html#register-java.nio.channels.Selector-int-) your channels (streams - you have to use `SocketChannel` instead of `InputStream`/`OutputStream`) with the selector, and [wait](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#select--) for one or more to have data, all on one thread. The selector also has a [`wakeup`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#wakeup--) method which causes it to stop waiting immediately, in case you want it to stop waiting for a reason that has nothing to do with channels.